# How can I merge multiple rows with same ID into one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I merge multiple rows with same ID into one row.

I have table:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| ID |  A   |  B   |  C   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | 123  | 31   | 456  |
|  1 | 412  | NULL | 1    |
|  2 | 567  | 38   | 4    |
|  2 | 567  | NULL | NULL |
|  3 | 2    | NULL | NULL |
|  3 | 5    | NULL | NULL |
|  4 | 6    | 1    | NULL |
|  4 | 8    | NULL | 5    |
|  4 | NULL | NULL | 5    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

I want to have table :
I have table:

```
+----+-----+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+----+
| ID |  A  |  B   |  C   | A2  |  B2  |  C2  |  A3  |  B3  | C3 |
+----+-----+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+----+
|  1 | 123 | 31   | 456  | 412 | NULL | 1    |      |      |    |
|  2 | 567 | 38   | 4    | 567 | NULL | NULL |      |      |    |
|  3 |   2 | NULL | NULL |   5 | NULL | NULL |      |      |    |
|  4 |   6 | 1    | NULL |   8 | NULL | 5    | NULL | NULL |  5 |
+----+-----+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+----+
```

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server, they are two different products, please pick one; if you're looking for sql-server the answer is 'self join'.

Comment: @Random_User looks more like a pivot to me.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Because SQL is a unorderd set of data without using ORDER BY.. Because you want more or less want to covert record number into column number you need to have to use ORDER BY.. The problem is that your example data doesn't contain a column where we can identify a order from like a primary key with auto_increment or a datetime colomn. It's possible with this data but the results won't be stabile without using ORDER BY because SQL databases are free to return the records in anny order without using ORDER BY.

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this?????

Comment: are you trying to do this with a dynamic amount of duplicates or can we assume 3? 4? is the max. (if so this is easy LEFT joins)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

1 :- Please Change data table structure to disallow null value.

[image]

2. Query :-

   ```
   SELECT 
       GROUP_CONCAT(if (`A` ='0', 'NOVAL', `A`)SEPARATOR '----') as A,
       GROUP_CONCAT(if (`B` ='0', 'NOVAL', `B`)SEPARATOR '----') as B,
       GROUP_CONCAT(if (`C` ='0', 'NOVAL', `C`)SEPARATOR '----') as C 
   FROM que1
   GROUP BY id
   ```

Now You can get the value using mysql_fetch_array

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. If I want to store the values with the same ID in different column. How can I code for that?

Comment: Why should you create new column.? You can go with my answer